# SQL Server Restore from one database to another

Tags: sql-server

One of our devs backed up a dev database, and then restored it in production. It's a new database for a new app that was deployed last night intentionally to prod.

Now in the backupset table (`msdb.dbo.backupset`) on prod, I can see a record for the dev database, with a backup start date time of when the restore was done.

Record from prod backupset table:

```
name:         DatabaseName_UAT-Full Database Backup
server_name:  COMPNAME-SQLDEV02
machine_name: COMPNAME-SQLDEV02
```

I would not expect to see this record. Can anyone explain why restore would insert into the backupset table on prod?

Can I delete this record from the `msdb.dbo.backupset` table? Or not such a good idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"It just does".  Its just meta data about the backup.

The Books Online article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186299.aspx hints at it, albeit not very well in the "Remarks" section.  From that article you'll see a reference to [sp_delete_backuphistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188328.aspx).  So yes you can safely remove it if you need to.

The info that goes into that backupset table, from a restore, is pulled out of the backup itself.  Run:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'Path to backup file';
```

and you'll find the information.